# Check the expected value substring to match either of the strings in Protractor Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to verify substring of a value to match with either of the strings.
I tried the ways as follows : 
1) expect(row.getText()).toContain('Håkan Åström' || 'Hakan Astrom')

in this verification the 2nd string is not being checked so throwing fail of the step
2) expect(row.getText()).toBeIn('Håkan Åström','Hakan Astrom')

TypeError: Object # has no method 'toBeIn' - error is seen.
Can any one share the solution that can be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.toMatch(RegExp)`. Your regular expression can match your expected string:

```
expect(row.getText()).toMatch(/H[aå]kan [AÅ]str[oö]m/)
```